# Error using IF statement in Batch Files (Windows)

Tags: string, batch-file, if-statement

I am trying to use IF statement in the below code.

```
@echo off
SET a=
SET b=HELLO WORLD
echo %b%
if [%a%] == [] echo "String A is empty"
if [%b%] == [] echo "String B is empty"
```

I am getting the output as below

```
HELLO WORLD
"String A is empty"
WORLD] was unexpected at this time.
```

Why is `WORLD] was unexpected at this time.` appearing in the output. Can you please point out the error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
SET a=
SET b=HELLO WORLD
echo %b%
if "%a%" == "" echo "String A is empty"
if "%b%" == "" echo "String B is empty"
```

This is because the space in `%b%` and is taken as two arguments to if.Quotes can be used to pass arguments with delimiters but not `[]`

Answer (score 2):

Read [Using "Double Quotes"](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

> If a single parameter contains spaces, you can still pass it as one
>   item by surrounding in "quotes" - this works well for long filenames.

The same is valid for any command *token*:

```
if [HELLO WORLD] == [] echo "String B is empty" 
         ↑↑ command line parser expects compare operator here like == EQU GTR etc.
```

Use

```
if "%a%" == "" echo "String A is empty"
if "%b%" == "" echo "String B is empty"
```

Answer (score 1):

A better solution if all you want to know is "is the variable empty" is

```
if defined a (echo a is defined) else (echo a is not defined)
```

naturally, `if not defined ...` is also available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

{ @echo off
SET a=
SET b=HELLO WORLD
echo %b%
if %a%== (what you want a to be) echo "String A is empty"
if %b%== "HELLO WORLD" echo "String B is empty"